# Is DateTime.Now.AddHours(custom) possible?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, console, int

I was just wondering if this is possible:

```
int custom = Console.ReadLine(); //or string custom?
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Add(custom);
```

I know that `Console.ReadLine()` equals to `string`. But nevertheless I am certain that this is somehow possible. Google couldn't help me so I thought I'd be the first one to ask. (Or I just suck at searching)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `DateTime.Now.AddHours` - it's worth focusing on the very specific problem you're facing, which is the conversion from `string` to `int`.

Comment: You mean from `Console.ReadLine();` to `DateTime`? I know that I'll have to convert it, but at every attempt that I tried I just got errors. Well, I'm gonna go and look into this. Thanks.

Comment: No, to `int`. Your first line doesn't compile, and doesn't have anything to do with `DateTime`.

Comment: This was just a quick example. I know it shouldn't be an `int`.

Comment: Why would it not be an `int`? It makes perfect sense for it to be an `int`. If you *don't* want it to be an `int`, you should say what you *do* want, otherwise you're wasting the time of people answering you.

Comment: I don't know what format it should be, I'm relatively a beginner of C#. This is just a small snippit of my code. Basicly I don't want the `DateTime.AddHours();` to be the same forever. I want to change it every time I run my application.

Comment: Right, so what do you want the user to input? Just a whole number of hours? That's an `int`, so you need to convert the user input to an `int` as the very first step.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. May I ask you if you know a really compact way?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working via `int custom = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`. Thanks anyways.

Comment: That won't handle invalid user input cleanly. RGraham's answer is better than that.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it'll run through a task scheduler. So the input will always be the same.

Comment: How can a task scheduler get console input? This sounds like you haven't provided appropriate context to get the most appropriate answer...

Comment: Wherever the input is going to get put also doesn't matter, because the output remains the same. I just used `Console.Write/ReadLine();` to simplify this entire problem.

Comment: I think you're missing the point: it *does* matter, because the most appropriate way of converting the data from `string` to `int` differs based on the interaction model.

Comment: I know, I understand. But it works doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you're missing my point. By not thinking about how to ask the question most appropriately, you've wasted people's time. You should *actually* have been asking "How should I convert a string to an integer in an unattended process?" which is not *at all* the question you asked.

Comment: I didn't knew it at the time. And like I already said: I'm just a beginner. And it's a bit ironic that you're saying that I'm wasting everyones time `in this case: yours` while you are using your time to respond to my inappropriate question. Don't you think?

Comment: You didn't know whether you'd be reading the string from the console or as part of a task schedule? That seems unlikely. I was hoping that you might learn from this for when you next ask a question. It isn't clear that it's getting through though. Oh well - I'm done here. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the `ReadLine()` result as an `int`:

```
int custom = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out custom)) {
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddHours(custom));
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!");
}
```